# What happens after submitting an iOS app for review?

Tags: iphone

I have been looking around for an answer for a specific question but just got hints for it here and there. I want to know when i submit an app for review for the AppStore:

First, how long does the review process usually take? I know that it may vary but just want to have rough estimate if possible

Second, when an app is accepted does it go automatically to the app store or the developer has the control over when to release it there?

Cheers
AF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. From my experience review takes about 2 weeks recently, but it varied from 2 days to about a month in the past.
2. When you submit an application you have an option - whether to make application available on appstore immediately after it was approved by Apple, or hold it before developer does that manually, so if you did not select that option then Application should be published on Appstore by default. (See pages 75-76 in [iTunesConnect Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) (warning - large pdf file here))

Answer (score 7):

[image]

check out details, which is my recent app on appstore,
It take 1 week for approval , As I remember, it was taken 3 days too once.
Time taken to publish is all in their hand.

App will be publish directly to appstore.
But you can remember the option for publish by you or apple :) at the time of submitting app